# Python parse comma seperated nested brackets using Pyparsing

Tags: python, parsing, nested-lists, pyparsing

I want to parse a comma separated nested brackets into nested list:

```
from pyparsing import nestedExpr
str = r'[["http://google.com","Jose Rivas","http://google.com","some_guid"],"a year ago",null,null,4,null,"1003136023",["https://www.yahoo.com","Do it",null,"0ahU_pv"],null,null,"ChZDSUhNMG","0ahUKEwjBr"]'

z = nestedExpr('[', ']').parseString(str).asList()
```

this is what i get:

[image]

why do i get ',' (a single comma) as list item or ,null,null,null, for example?
How to fix it?

Comment: Why do you use pyparsing and don't use a usual json package to parse this json?

Comment: This is not json, json has a name for each variable

Comment: it's a usual json, try my code in answer block... JSON is dicts + lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a usual JSON, try to parse it with `json` package:

```
import json

raw = r'[["http://google.com","Jose Rivas","http://google.com","some_guid"],"a year ago",null,null,4,null,"1003136023",["https://www.yahoo.com","Do it",null,"0ahU_pv"],null,null,"ChZDSUhNMG","0ahUKEwjBr"]'
data = json.loads(raw)

print(data)
```